# to change to https by http - safari shows our website not feel right

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https, safari

We got our SSL certificate yesterday . This I have now embedded and redirected the old address on the https page . Now our site is no longer displayed in Safari correctly. In Chrome and Firefox, however, everything is working properly. I'm at a loss on what to do.

Our page is: https://www.zweistein.design

Comment: Your style.css has lots of syntax errors: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zweistein.design%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: Thank you very much. I have realized my problem . I minimized to only my css file . Then I have the file with css beautify again formatted back . Here louder syntax error arose . That's what I thought as a last resort .

Answer (score 1):

As I do not have Safari running on my PC I cannot double check this, however opening the source code on Firefox revealed a HTML semantic error. You appear to have a DIV tag in your HEAD tag.

DIV is a "flow content" tag and should not appear inside your HEAD tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

Again I cannot test this so I am not sure if this is what is causing your issue, but definitely worth correcting.

[image]